# AttributeError: module 'razorpay' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, django, razorpay

**I'm using pipenv --python 3.6 environment and I installed razorpay(1.2.0) and  all requirements but I still getting this error.**

When I click on submit button this error shows up:

[image]

views.py file:

```
if request.method == "POST":
                name = request.POST['name']
                amount = request.POST['amount']
        
                client = razorpay.Client(auth=("My-key-id", "My-secret-key"))
                # client.set_app_details({"title" : "django", "version" : "3.2.3"})
        
                payment = client.order.create({'amount' : amount, 'currency' : 'INR' , 'payment_capture' : '1'})
                print(payment) 
        
                coffee = Coffee(name=name, amount=amount, payment_id=payment['id'])
                data = {
                    payment : payment
                    }
                return render(request, 'razorpay/donate_page.html', data)
```

donate_page.html file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <img src="{% static './assets/images/coffee-bg.png' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="img">
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'donate_page' %}" class="col-md-5 offset-1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the correct name, so that we will help you in case of donation-related problems.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input  name="amount"  type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57"  placeholder="Enter amount"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-btn w-100 mt-3 mb-3">Donate</button>
 
    </form>
</div>
</main>

{% if payment %}
{% csrf_token %}
<form action="{% url 'success' %}" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
        data-key="My-key-id" // Enter the Test API Key ID generated from Dashboard → Settings → API Keys
        data-amount="{{ payment.amount }}" // Amount is in currency subunits. Hence, 29935 refers to 29935 paise or ₹299.35.
        data-currency="INR"// You can accept international payments by changing the currency code. Contact our Support Team to enable International for your account
        data-order_id="{{ payment.id }}"// Replace with the order_id generated by you in the backend.
        data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
        data-name="Donate for Coffee"
        data-description="A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami"
        data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
        data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
        data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
        data-theme.color="#F37254"
    ></script>
    <input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">

</form>
{% endif %}
```

**I tried to remove the entire environment and create a new one but it is also not working.**

Comment: Do you per chance have some file named `razorpay.py` in your own code?

Comment: Have you imported razorpay? As @AbdulAzizBarkat said you may have some other file named `razorpay.py` and this is causing the conflict. Try renaming that file. It will be easier to fix the issue if you can show the complete error.

Comment: yes i imported razorpay, There is no file named razorpay.py but my app name is razorpay

Comment: @Princep generally one should not name their apps the same as a third party package they use. You will need to rename it as that is what is causing your error.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Vallaaa, error gone, Thank you guys